# AES encrypt in .NET with zero padding and decrypt with Node.js

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to decrypt some data with a NodeJS.

This data was created with C# and the AES-CBC-256 algorithm.
The keySize and blockSize are 256 and the Padding is **ZeroPadding**.

I cant' decrypt it with Node.js, the error is:

```
Error: error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv.slice(0, 16));
decrypted = decipher.update(encryptedPayloadBuffer, 'base64', 'ascii');
decrypted += decipher.final('ascii');
decipher = null;

return decrypted;
```

I use the library "crypto". I read somewhere that node.js decryption works only with PKSC7 padding. Is it true ? I can't change anything in the C# project, I must find a solution on the node side.

Can you help me please ?

Edit: I tried to disable autoPadding with this:

```
decipher.setAutoPadding(false);
//next line of code:
//decrypted = decipher.update(encryptedPayloadBuffer, 'base64', 'ascii');
```

But I received this error:

```
Error: error:0606508A:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:data not multiple of block length
```

Comment: It's not AES if you have a block size of 256 bit. Please make clear what you're using.

Comment: @ArtjomB. It may well be that you can force a C# AES implementation into performing Rijndael-256, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @ArtjomB I'm sure it is AES. Here is the implementation: https://gist.github.com/VivienAdnot/e9a96fea04bccfa613ec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between AES and Rijndael. Both specify key sizes of 128, 192 and 256 bits, but only Rijndael provides all three block sizes: 128, 192 and 256 bits. AES is actually Rijndael with a fixed block size of 128 bit.

Node.js uses OpenSSL to provide all the available ciphers (`crypto.getCiphers()`). If there is no rijndael implementation available for your version, then you can't use node.js' Crypto module. You'll either need to find a node module that implements Rijndael or simply set the block size to 128 bit in your C# code.

Comment: Thank you, i understand the problem now. I searched for another node module than crypto but I couldn't find one at the moment. I hope someone knows it and will write it here.

Answer (score 0):

A look at the [Crypto Node.js doc](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createdecipheriv_algorithm_key_iv) finds this:

> decipher.setAutoPadding(auto_padding=true)
>
> You can disable auto padding if the data has been encrypted without
>   standard block padding to prevent decipher.final from checking and
>   removing it. Can only work if the input data's length is a multiple of
>   the ciphers block size. You must call this before streaming data to
>   decipher.update.

Try `decipher.setAutoPadding(false)` before `decipher.update.`

Comment: Don't forget to remove the zero padding after decryption.

Comment: @Jim Flood. Thanks for your answer. I already tried this, but I encountered this error: data not multiple of block length